# How to keep indexes when combining matrices?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have 2 indexes, one named NIM, and one named Total Score. Both have 100X1 block matrices.

When I run the code below the index gets removed.

`Final_Score = np.hstack((NIM, np.atleast_2d(total_score).T))`

Is there a way to combine several matrices into one and keep their indexes?

Comment: Use `pd.concat` instead `np.hstack`?

Comment: oh i tried using that as well, the table instead stack, and make 200 rows of matrix the first part have right one turn NaN, the next 100 rows is NaN on the right side

Comment: Try to use `axis=0` or `axis=1` and `ignore_index=True`. Maybe if you could update your post with a sample of your 2 indexes?

Comment: it is okay, I get the answer already thanks for the enlightment

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the same code but added:

`pd.DataFrame(Final_score,columns=['NIM','Final Score'])`

Now, I can change np array into pd.